# Is superuser.com for asking questions about Python?

Tags: discussion

I've heard that superuser.com is a place to ask questions related to Linux (Bash Shell). Is  superuser.com also a place to ask questions about Python? If not, would questions related to Python coding be asked at stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 5):

While we [allow some shell scripting](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2343/preferred-location-for-shell-scripting-questions) questions, Python is considered more of a "proper" programming language.

Python programming questions would be considered off topic here and should be asked at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 3):

In short:

Questions about running the Python *compiler* or Python-compiled *programs*
are acceptable (within reason).

Questions about *coding* these programs or *debugging* are off-subject.